# Opening login but unable to proceed

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            GUI login = new GUI();
            login.setVisible(true);
            login.setResizable(false);
            if(GUI.loggedIn = true){
                Loader loader = new Loader();
                loader.setVisible(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When the GUI (login) has been completed it doesn't open the loader. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Once the user is logged it sets it to: loggedIn = true;

Answer (score 1):

`if(GUI.loggedIn = true)` should be `if(GUI.loggedIn)`

Basically you should use `==` for comparing and not `=` which is the assigning operator, but when comparing boolean, you don't have to write `== true` because it's redundant.

This is a very good opportunity to understand why using `if(something)` is preferable (I think it's a must) if you want to see if it's *true* instead of writing `if(something == true)`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I have changed it, but still no success.

Comment: Where did you set `loggedIn` to be true?